# Could not internally obtain zookeeper handle

Tags: juju, maas

Actually, after a successfull deployement of the bootstrap node in  maas/juju environment, it seems that adding a new node was a kind of impossible to do figure out. The node02 is being installed and we can see in juju status :

```
,534 INFO Connecting to environment...
,319 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node01
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-cf3eb63c-8a27-11e2-a9f6-0050561dd02a/
    instance-state: unknown
  4:
    agent-state: not-started
    dns-name: node02
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-3550ded6-8be1-11e2-bfa6-0050561dd02a/
    instance-state: unknown
```

As you can see the node02 did not start that s because of the following output in /var/log/juju/machine-agent.log:

```
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1039, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/agents/base.py", line 210, in connect
    self.config["zookeeper_servers"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txzookeeper/retry.py", line 302, in connect
    return self.client.connect(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txzookeeper/client.py", line 468, in connect
    self._servers, callback, self._session_timeout)
zookeeper.ZooKeeperException: Could not internally obtain zookeeper handle
```

Basically, Zookeeeper is not running in this node and of course in other nodes.
is there any explanation for who experienced this problem ?

Another hit when running is maas node : juju debug-log we can see something like :

```
,077 provision:maas: juju.state.expose DEBUG: Assigned units for machine 6: old=None, 
,173 provision:maas: juju.maas WARNING: Firewalling is not yet implemented
```

is firewalling setting are required to run juju env???

Am still fillig my list experienced troubleshooting with juju/maas installation!!!

Comment: In node2, what is the output of `nc -z node01 2181; echo $?` What are the iptables rules in your environment? Could you paste all the /etc/init/juju*.conf?